# Parse custom class (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform

In a nutshell, I have created register and login functionalities. The problem is that I do not want the information/retrieved from the default User class, but from a custom one, such as Customers, however, i do not know how to change it.

This is how I refer to the default class (User).

```
 $scope.signUp = function(form) {
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("password", form.password);
        user.set("username", form.username);

    user.signUp(null, {
      success: function(user) {
window.location = 'myprofile.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to sign up:  " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });    
  };

  $scope.logIn = function(form) {
    Parse.User.logIn(form.lusername, form.lpassword, {
      success: function(user) {
  window.location = 'admin.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.logOut = function(form) {
    Parse.User.logOut();
window.location = 'index.html'
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give more details?

Comment: Sure. In parse I want to store user registration information in a newly created class called "Customers", and be able to retrieve login information from that class. The problem is that I only know how to store and retrieve information from the default class called "User:

Comment: Something like. `var Customer = Parse.Object.extend("Customer");` ?

Comment: precisely, and thank you for the suggestion. I am trying to work out the following:     Parse.User.logIn(form.lusername, form.lpassword, {
      success: function(user) {
  window.location = 'userinterfaceSelect.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });